# How can I get a constant initialized by a value in .yml file? (spring boot/java)

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, yaml, constants

If I have something like this:

```
public class Roles {
    public static final String ENVIRONMENT_DEPENDENT_ADMIN_ROLE = "ADMIN";
    private Roles() {}
}
```

Which ends up being utilized in Spring Boot as this at the controller level:

```
@RolesAllowed(ENVIRONMENT_DEPENDENT_ADMIN_ROLE)
```

This annotation requires a constant so there's no easy way to get around it.

The issue is, is that each role has a different name that needs to be taken in based on the environment it's being deployed in.

Is there anyway to extract the value of this before compilation from the relevant environment application.yml?

Example *application-dev.yml*:

```
app:
    roles:
        admin: devappadminrole
```

So therefore it ends up being this at runtime:

```
public static final String ENVIRONMENT_DEPENDENT_ADMIN_ROLE = "devappadminrole";
```

I understand this is bad practice and goes against Java coding practices in many aspects but this is what was asked of me.

I have tried looking into a few compile time options such as a find and replace in the Roles java file which seems a little hacky. I've looked into editing the build.gradle script as well.

Comment: This is not possible as it's a constant. How do you configure the security? You could do a translation from the configured roles to those used in the annotations.